# Selected enemy off camera

Tags: unity, camera, gui

I'm facing a problem with a game I'm making.
Currently I can select an enemy and mark it as shown on the image: [image]

But now I want to show the position of the selected enemy on the screen when it's off camera.
So my questions are:

1. How do I know when an enemy is off camera.
2. How can I show in GUI an arrow on the edge of the screen that points to the position of that enemy. Perhaps something related to what I did to point towards the crosshair?

```
Vector3 positionOnScreen = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos + Vector3.forward * range);
Vector3 targetDir = positionOnScreen - transform.position;
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you need [location Indicator](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/positioning-on-screen-indicators-to-point-to-off-screen-targets--gamedev-6644)?

Comment: Yes, thank you, this was what I needed for the second question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can easily know if a world point is visible by a given camera using [Camera.WorldToViewportPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToViewportPoint.html). This will return a `Vector2` that represents the position of your object in the viewport. A viewport goes from [0,0] (bottom left) to [1,1] (top right). If the returned value has a component lower than 0 or higher than 1 it means that the object is offscreen (or partially offscreen).
2. As Seyed Morteza Kamali suggested in his comment, you can point the position of your object using basic [intersection](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/positioning-on-screen-indicators-to-point-to-off-screen-targets--gamedev-6644)

---

About the second point the solution is all about linear function (y = ax + b).

````cs
            Vector2 a = viewport_pos; // viewport position of your offscreen item
            Vector2 b = target_viewport_pos; // viewport position of the target (in your case 0.5;0.5 for the 

            if (b.x == a.x || a.y == b.y) return;

            // y = px + d
            float p = (b.y - a.y) / (b.x - a.x);
            float d = a.y - p * a.x;

            float new_vy;
            float new_vx;

            // Check the axis with the biggest difference to define on which side of the screen you should display the arrow.
            float diff_x = a.x - b.x;
            float diff_y = a.y - b.y;

            // Display the arrow on the left/right sides
            if (diff_x > diff_y)
            {
                new_vx = viewport_pos.x < 0 ? 0f : 1f;
                new_vy = new_vx * p + d;
            }
            else // Display the arrow on the top/down sides
            {
                new_vy = viewport_pos.y < 0 ? 0f : 1f;
                new_vx = (new_vy - d) / p;
            }

            // This is the position of your arrow.
            Vector3 new_pos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(new_vx, new_vy));
```
````

Comment: Can you add the information from the link in your point 2 to your answer in case the link breaks? We generally try to answer questions in our answers themselves and not just link to external websites which might provide an answer for a while and then disappear or change their URLs.

Comment: Hey @Philipp sure, I'll do that asap.

Comment: Thanks, very well explained. The only remaining question that I have is that, since in the last line of the code says that the Arrow has a World position, would that also apply to a GUI element? Because I want the arrow to be part of the GUI.

Comment: Then just use ViewportToScreenPoint instead of ViewportToWorldPoint ;)

Comment: I've tried using new_pos = mainCamera.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector3(new_vx, new_vy)); but something is not right, because sometimes the x value of this position is negative.

Comment: Hi @Ivictorino, I've been able to figure mostly what was wrong. In first place the comparison if (diff_x > diff_y) should be (Mathf.Abs(diff_x) > Mathf.Abs(diff_y)), otherwise it wont enter inside of the condition depending on its position (I had cases where the diffs where diff_x = 0.03 and diff_y = -0.8 and was putting the arrow on the right side. Also I've been having some trouble when the enemy is on my back, because in that case the x and y components of the viewport position are inside my range, but not the z one. This was making the arrow a bit crazy sometimes

Comment: Ok I managed to find a solution for the issue when the enemy is on my back. In order to do so I use the camera locally transformed position of the enemy instead of using the screenPosition returned by camera.WorldToScreenPoint(enemy.transform.position). the code would be as folllows:  `Matrix4x4 cameraMatrix = mainCamera.transform.worldToLocalMatrix;
        Vector3 EnemyViewportPos = cameraMatrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(enemy.transform.position);
        EnemyViewportPos.z = 0;`

Comment: Congrats! Thanks for the update. I'm glad my answer helped you. Would you mind checking it as a valid answer please?

Comment: Sure! Thanks again for your help!